# How to integrate Angularjs and Salesforce?

Tags: angularjs, salesforce, visualforce

I'm trying to test some example Angularjs app in Salesforce. When I test it running

```
grunt serve
```

on my browser, it works fine. So I put the code in a Visualforce page and it doesn't show all the content correctly. Seems like it is a problem with the #/ and the $routeProvider part.

The code (the initial code of the angular generator from Yeoman) in my Visualforce page:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="griApp">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#js-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">gri</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a ng-href="#/about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a ng-href="#/">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> from the Yeoman team</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
</body>
```

In my real code I'm using correctly the URLFOR to include the files of an static resource.

My app.js is:

```
angular
  .module('griApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngAria',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'about'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

Hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Need to be a bit more specific about what is actually happening. Any errors in console? Does url change to expected `#/` path? If so what happens then? If not what happens?

Comment: Thank you @charlietfl ! There is no error in console. The url change correctly. For the moment, nothing happens. But it should display different text for each menu option. I've been looking and trying examples of how to integrate Angular With Salesforce but I have not yet succeeded. I suspect that a problem could be in $ routerProvider, in views. At that point, the route is not assigned with URLFor, and I think that it could also be wrong.

Comment: I don't know salesforce but since the angular routes are hash based the server only ever knows about the main page url. Check browser dev tools network. My guess would be template paths will need modifying but not sure

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help! I'll try that.

Comment: Where did you place the html templates .. are they ng-template ?

Answer (score 0):

I have integrated salesforce and angularjs. I have created Apex components corresponding to each page and have placed the html content in ngTemplate and load via $templateCache.

so my app visualforce page looks like as follows

```
 <apex:component controller="APTS_ApttusLabAngularJS">

     <script type="text/ng-template" id="name.html">
        <!-- include your html and refer this name.html in your route
     </script>

 </apex:component>
```

I would advise you to use stateProvider instead.